# How to apply the app icon to the Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want to have that same/similar theme but instead of showing my app's name on the action bar, I would like it to display my app's icon.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)` on your `ActionBar`.